# Redraw polygon while changing window size with WPF 4

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, polygon

I'm making a WPF/C# program with a `Polygon` to make a triangle. When the size of my window changes, I want it to be redraw, so here is my WPF :

```
<Polygon  Name="Plg" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Polygon.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
    </Polygon.Fill>
</Polygon>
```

And here is my code in the `Window_SizeChanged` Event:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{        
    Plg.Points.Clear(); 
    Plg.Points.Add(new Point(Plg.ActualWidth / 2 , 0));
    Plg.Points.Add(new Point(2, Plg.ActualHeight));
    Plg.Points.Add(new Point(Plg.ActualWidth, Plg.ActualHeight));         
}
```

If i increase the size of the window, it works well, but if I try to reduce it, the triangle keeps the biggest size that it has. I also try with `RenderSize`, but the result is the same.

Is it a bug, or did i make something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this XAML, it works: (the grid is in the window)

```
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    <Polygon  Name="Plg" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Polygon.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
        </Polygon.Fill>
    </Polygon>
</Grid>
```

Change your code like this:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{        
    Plg.Points.Clear(); 
    Plg.Points.Add(new Point(myGrid.ActualWidth / 2 , 0));
    Plg.Points.Add(new Point(2, myGrid.ActualHeight));
    Plg.Points.Add(new Point(myGrid.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight));         
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't works, nothing appears. Also, the triangle hasn't the  size of my window, it's in a grid ;)